# Can Cake (of http://cakebuild.net) be used for deploying Azure WebApps

Tags: c#, azure, continuous-integration, cakebuild

Have been checking out Cake (at http://cakebuild.net) and am wondering if it can be used for deploying webapps and/or accessing virtual servers fro deploying of release packages.

I like the idea of cake being a deployment framework in C# so being in the same language as core development.

Are there any examples of azure deployments that I could get access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few ways you can deploy Azure using Cake, either through prebuilding site using some CI service like VSTS/AppVeyor and then publishing the artifacts using web deploy, git or ftp (there's a few Cake addins that can help with that [Cake.WebDeploy](https://github.com/SharpeRAD/Cake.WebDeploy), [Cake.Git](https://github.com/wcomab/Cake_Git) or [Cake.FTP](https://github.com/cake-contrib/Cake.Ftp) or using Azure built-in deployment engine Kudu and a custom deployment script using Cake.

To assist with the Kudu deploy/build environment you can use the [Cake.Kudu](https://github.com/wcomab/Cake.Kudu) addin.

The first step is to tell Kudu that you've got an custom deployment script, you do this by adding a ".deployment" file to the root of your repository with the content of

```
[config]
command = deploy.cmd
```

The deploy.cmd could look something like this to install & launch Cake

```
@echo off

IF NOT EXIST "Tools" (md "Tools")

IF NOT EXIST "Tools\Addins" (MD "Tools\Addins")

nuget install Cake -ExcludeVersion -OutputDirectory "Tools" -Source https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/

Tools\Cake\Cake.exe deploy.cake -verbosity=Verbose
```

And deploy.cake could look something like this:

```
#tool "nuget:https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/?package=xunit.runner.console"

#tool "nuget:https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/?package=KuduSync.NET"

#addin "nuget:https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/?package=Cake.Kudu"

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// ARGUMENTS

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


var target = Argument<string>("target", "Default");

var configuration = Argument<string>("configuration", "Release");

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// GLOBAL VARIABLES

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var webRole = (EnvironmentVariable("web_role") ?? string.Empty).ToLower();

var solutionPath = MakeAbsolute(File("./src/MultipleWebSites.sln"));

string outputPath = MakeAbsolute(Directory("./output")).ToString();

string testsOutputPath = MakeAbsolute(Directory("./testsOutputPath")).ToString();


DirectoryPath websitePath,

                websitePublishPath,

                testsPath;


FilePath projectPath,

            testsProjectPath;

switch(webRole)

{

    case "api":

        {

            websitePath = MakeAbsolute(Directory("./src/Api"));

            projectPath = MakeAbsolute(File("./src/Api/Api.csproj"));

            testsPath = MakeAbsolute(Directory("./src/Api.Tests"));

            testsProjectPath = MakeAbsolute(File("./src/Api.Tests/Api.Tests.csproj"));

            websitePublishPath = MakeAbsolute(Directory("./output/_PublishedWebsites/Api"));

            break;

        }

    case "frontend":

        {

            websitePath = MakeAbsolute(Directory("./src/Frontend"));

            projectPath = MakeAbsolute(File("./src/Frontend/Frontend.csproj"));

            testsPath = MakeAbsolute(Directory("./src/Frontend.Tests"));

            testsProjectPath = MakeAbsolute(File("./src/Frontend.Tests/Frontend.Tests.csproj"));

            websitePublishPath = MakeAbsolute(Directory("./output/_PublishedWebsites/Frontend"));

            break;

        }

    case "backoffice":

        {

            websitePath = MakeAbsolute(Directory("./src/Backoffice"));

            projectPath = MakeAbsolute(File("./src/Backoffice/Backoffice.csproj"));

            testsPath = MakeAbsolute(Directory("./src/Backoffice.Tests"));

            testsProjectPath = MakeAbsolute(File("./src/Backoffice.Tests/Backoffice.Tests.csproj"));

            websitePublishPath = MakeAbsolute(Directory("./output/_PublishedWebsites/Backoffice"));

            break;

        }

    default:

        {

            throw new Exception(

            string.Format(

                    "Unknown web role {0}!",

                    webRole

                )

            );

        }

}


if (!Kudu.IsRunningOnKudu)

{

    throw new Exception("Not running on Kudu");

}


var deploymentPath = Kudu.Deployment.Target;

if (!DirectoryExists(deploymentPath))

{

    throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(

        string.Format(

            "Deployment target directory not found {0}",

            deploymentPath

            )

        );

}


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// SETUP / TEARDOWN

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


Setup(() =>

{

    // Executed BEFORE the first task.

    Information("Running tasks...");

});


Teardown(() =>

{

    // Executed AFTER the last task.

    Information("Finished running tasks.");

});


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// TASK DEFINITIONS

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


Task("Clean")

    .Does(() =>

{

    //Clean up any binaries

    Information("Cleaning {0}", outputPath);

    CleanDirectories(outputPath);


    Information("Cleaning {0}", testsOutputPath);

    CleanDirectories(testsOutputPath);


    var cleanWebGlobber = websitePath + "/**/" + configuration + "/bin";

    Information("Cleaning {0}", cleanWebGlobber);

    CleanDirectories(cleanWebGlobber);


    var cleanTestsGlobber = testsPath + "/**/" + configuration + "/bin";

    Information("Cleaning {0}", cleanTestsGlobber);

    CleanDirectories(cleanTestsGlobber);

});


Task("Restore")

    .Does(() =>

{

    // Restore all NuGet packages.

    Information("Restoring {0}...", solutionPath);

    NuGetRestore(solutionPath);

});


Task("Build")

    .IsDependentOn("Clean")

    .IsDependentOn("Restore")

    .Does(() =>

{

    // Build target web & tests.

    Information("Building web {0}", projectPath);

    MSBuild(projectPath, settings =>

        settings.SetPlatformTarget(PlatformTarget.MSIL)

            .WithProperty("TreatWarningsAsErrors","true")

            .WithProperty("OutputPath", outputPath)

            .WithTarget("Build")

            .SetConfiguration(configuration));


    Information("Building tests {0}", testsProjectPath);

    MSBuild(testsProjectPath, settings =>

        settings.SetPlatformTarget(PlatformTarget.MSIL)

            .WithProperty("TreatWarningsAsErrors","true")

            .WithProperty("ReferencePath", outputPath)

            .WithProperty("OutputPath", testsOutputPath)

            .WithTarget("Build")

            .SetConfiguration(configuration));

});


Task("Run-Unit-Tests")

    .IsDependentOn("Build")

    .Does(() =>

{

    XUnit2(testsOutputPath + "/**/*.Tests.dll", new XUnit2Settings {

        NoAppDomain = true

        });

});


Task("Publish")

    .IsDependentOn("Run-Unit-Tests")

    .Does(() =>

{

    Information("Deploying web from {0} to {1}", websitePublishPath, deploymentPath);

    Kudu.Sync(websitePublishPath);

});



Task("Default")

    .IsDependentOn("Publish");



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// EXECUTION

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


RunTarget(target);
```

In the above scenario it supports a solution with 3 different websites and the one that is published is based on an appsetting.

For .NET Core web apps the flow is similar, basically something like below:

1. DotNetCoreRestore
2. DotNetCoreBuild
3. DotNetCorePublish
4. Kudu.Sync

There's a couple of good blog posts on deploying to Azure with Cake:

- http://cakebuild.net/blog/2015/10/cake-addin-kudu
- https://hackernoon.com/delivering-functions-with-cake-4b269c50f817
- https://daveaglick.com/posts/publishing-to-azure-using-cake-and-web-deploy